# R- help in creating a matrix for finding similar values

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following data frame 
df<- data.frame(Class = c("S1","S1","s2","s2","S3","S3","S3","S3"), Brand = c("B1","B2","B2","B3","B1","B2","B3","B4"))

I want  to count the common brands between two classes  and display the output as a matrix. An example of the output is displayed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d3cy.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: You may need `table(df)`

Comment: You "want to list the brands" but in the required output, there is no list of brands. Please explain, how the output is supposed to be constructed. What ist "a matrix given above"?

Comment: I don't want the brands to be listed but only a count of the common brands in the output. The output is attached in the link. (click on 'output')Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are more elegant solutions but this gives the outcome you want

A list containing the unique values for Brand, for each Class.

```
my_list <- tapply(df$Class, df$Brand, unique)
```

A count of the number of the shared Brand elements, that is, intersections for Class. This is stored in a matrix.

```
my_matrix <- do.call(what = cbind, 
                     args = lapply(1:length(my_list), function(x){
                       lapply(1:length(my_list), function(y){
                         length(intersect(my_list[[x]], my_list[[y]]))
                       })
                     })
    )
```

The resulting matrix can be named for clarity.

```
colnames(my_matrix) <- unique(df$Class)
rownames(my_matrix) <- unique(df$Class)
```

Comment: Thanks Juan. This worked. I interchanged Class and Brand here -> tapply(df$Class, df$Brand, unique). I have a total of 378 classes and 209 brands, Is there a way to improve the process time because it took  2 minutes.

Comment: Try using the package `parallel`, I think it can help with the computation time.

Comment: Thanks Juan. Will try the parallel  package.